# How to join two tables of PostgreSQL In node.js using Bookshelfjs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I have two table.

**Users**

1. id(pk)
2. name(varchar)
3. email(varchar)
4. role(Array)(Fk)

**Roles**

1. id(pk)
2. name(varchar)

I have created model for these table

```
 var Users= bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'Users'
});

var Roles= bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'Roles'
});
```

Now what i want , with user info to get Role information , and in my case roles can be more then one. how i can achive it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical many-to-many situation. Both models should have `belongsTo` defined and you should have a table named `roles_users` with corresponding ids.